# Cell change event in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prompt the message box after the changing value of specific cell value.

I am using sheet change event but i want to do it manually using macro or instead of sheet change event is there any event like cell change event only for specific rangename.

i am already  using worksheet_change i need event for a specific cell or specific range name.

can anyone suggest me macro or event for cell change?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event and just display the message box if `Target` is the cell (or part of the range) that you are interested in.  There are many, many, many examples available, both here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, to show you how to do this.

Comment: Keep in mind, `Worksheet_Change` will only work if you physically change the contents of the target cell(s), otherwise if your cell's value changes based on a formula, you might need to look at the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: @L42 - FWIW, that "duplicate" has a terrible accepted answer.  I don't know whether things were different back in 2009 (I don't think it was), but everything stated in the answer is inaccurate now.

Comment: @L42 I have just VTCed with that new link - it looks **much** better (and much closer to this question) than the first link you had.  Not sure what will happen when the question does get closed - maybe it will list both duplicates, or maybe it will list the old one (which is currently 2 votes, versus the single vote on the new one).

Comment: i am using worksheet_change but that is heavy function means it every times execute when i am changing any cell of specific sheet

Comment: i need only for specific range or specific cell

Comment: @JaydeepBobade If you check out the linked questions you will see that the first one shows how to do something **only** if the specific cell D2 was changed, and the second one shows how to do something **only** if the specific cell H5 was changed.